# Sample space of 4 people in 4 categories

Tags: probability, statistics

The problem is to find the number of elements in the sample space.

We have four patients and 4 categories of diseases.

Event A: All patients are in the same category

Event B: 2 patients belong to the same category

My question is why is the answer here $4^4$.

As far as I see it:

for one category (S...same category, D...different category):

A = {SSSS}

B ={SSDD, DSSD, DDSS, SDDS, SDSD, DSDS}

So why cant we just multiply 7 times 4 categories and get a sample space of 20?

Comment: First, $7\times 4 = 28\neq 20$... Next, the choice of sample space is a *choice*.  The only rules per se are that you must do it in such a way that all events you are interested in referring to must be subsets of your sample space.  Now... some sample spaces will be *preferred* for various reasons such as keeping the outcomes in the sample space equiprobable or aesthetically pleasing etc...

Comment: Overall, all 4 patients could be in 4 possible categories each which is $4\times4\times4\times4 = 4^4$. With 4 categories of diseases, there are 4 ways all the patients could be in the same category.  So sure it is true for Event A that the element SSSS could be replaced by disease category 1, 2, 3, or 4, and that is a straight multiplication, to 4 elements.  But for Event B, there are 4 ways the category can be the same and for each of those 4 there are 3 ways the other category can be different.  So now you can not simply multiply by 4.  This is a combinatorics problem of $n\choose{r}$.